# At the point $\sqrt{2}$ in the real line, does *every* n-ball around that point contain a rational?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it trivial to prove?

Obviously a ball of some radius will contain a rational number, but what about *for all* $\varepsilon > 0$ ?

Comment: It follows from the fact that the rational are dense in $\mathbb{R}$: that is, there is a sequence of rationals that converge to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: In fact every ball of positive radius no matter where the center contains a rational.

Comment: What do you mean by $n$-ball?

Comment: Intuitively, just approximate $\sqrt 2$ with a rational number to sufficient precision.

Comment: Maybe continued fractions of $\sqrt{2}$ or $a_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}\right)$ helps.

Comment: @GregoryGrant For $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r > 0$ An $n-ball$ is the set of points $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|a - x| < r $

Comment: Then it's confusing because $\sqrt{2}$ and "rationals" are in $\mathbb R^1$.  So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I should have said 1-ball

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is because your open ball is going to contain at least two different real numbers, between any two real numbers there is a rational number.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. An easy way of seeing is take the (infinite) decimal expansion of $\sqrt2$ (or for that matter any real number, rational or not).

Given an $\varepsilon>0$, we look for a number of the form $1/10^m$ that is less than that. Now take a number $x$ that agrees with $\sqrt2$ in the first $m$  (or $m+1$, to be safe) places after decimal point and then has only zeros in all the remaining positions: this $x$ is a rational number within $\varepsilon$ distance of $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to think of it this way.  Let $I$ be an open interval of length $\epsilon>0$.  Then there is a natural number $n$ such that $\frac1n<\epsilon/2$.  Now start at the origin and start walking along the real line taking steps of size $\frac1n$.  You cannot completely straddle the interval $I$ taking steps of that size, so one of the steps must land within $I$.  Say it's the $m$-th step.  Then $\frac mn\in I$.  And $\frac mn\in\mathbb Q$.